# How to revert an 'apt-get remove' action after pressing CTRL+Z

Tags: apt, process

I ran by mistake `apt-get remove WRONG_PACKAGE`, after realizing this, I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to break the process since removing that package started removing around 100+ other packages.

Now when I try to run `apt-get install REMOVED_ONES` it states:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Is there any way to revert it?

Comment: Did you run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' ? if yes, post its output too.

Comment: Added an answer that should cover a locking problem, the suspend state of a process and a explanation of what happened there.

Comment: No Akash, I didn't run that command. By mistake I pressed enter instead of N when I wanted to uninstall libjpgeg or something like that (to recompile it manually as I needed a newer version in order to compile something).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will **suspend** the process.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will **kill** the process.

Note that **suspending** a process will send it to the background until you call it again. Since it is suspended you can run another program. It will "look" like is gone but is not. It will actually tell you the Process ID that has been assigned to it before going to the background.

To know which processes are running on the background we use the `jobs` command, which would show all background running processes on the opened terminal with their respective background number.

To call the process again (Actually to continue the process where you left it) type `fg`.

`fg` means ForeGround. To bring to foreground from background if you want to have an idea of it. If you happen to have other suspended process, you can go to them by doing `fg 1` for process 1, `fg 2` for process 2 and so on.

Know that if you send a process to the background using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> you will send the process to the background but it will be stopped. To make it run again, simply run `bg` followed by the background ID job for that process, like `bg 2` for job 2 in the background.

The difference when applied to `apt-get` (Or aptitude or any other package manager) is that the lock files will not get erased when doing a remove/upgrade/install or that the repo file might get corrupted.

You will need to literally remove the files with `rm`.

Before removing anything try what the package manager suggests, in that case:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` in case you did an upgrade. In most cases (in ALL cases for me) I had to first delete the **lock** files as followed:

`sudo rm -fr /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
`sudo rm -fr /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

If by chance you want to remove the process (if it is still active) you can either look it up by using `ps -e` and finding the PID numer, then using `kill -9 PID` where PID is the number you found or issuing `sudo killall NAME_OF_PROCESS`

Alternative you can also do:

`sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock`
`sudo fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
`sudo rm -fr /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
`sudo rm -fr /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

After all of this you can either use the commands recommended by the app as I mentioned in the beginning or simply try to reinstall the package you mistakenly removed. I also recommend doing an `sudo apt-get update` just to make sure everything is correct.

Note that if the package removed all of those other packages, try first to install said package. For example if you did:

`sudo apt-get remove unity` by mistake, then first try to do the steps I mentioned and then install that precise package again:

`sudo apt-get install unity`.

If by chance it did not get uninstall then do:

`sudo -apt-get install --reinstall unity`

Comment: Great answer. You've mentioned killing apt-get, this reminds me of a friend of mine who disconnected his computer's power while apt-get was doing a dist-upgrade :) Heavy stuff.

Comment: @rafalcieslak Wow that happened to me but this time the power went off in the entire block and I was like 75% doing the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Luis! That solved the issue, after 20 minutes the system is back ok :D ( I was lucky to save the console in a separate file to see which packages were removed in the first place )

Comment: Glad to help @SorinTrimbitas

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once and ran the command as suggested. 
After you do that you can `apt-get install WRONG_PACKAGE`. It should reinstall all the packages it tried to remove. You do not need to install each one manually.